# Workflow or Script to prevent duplicates from being created

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-online

What is the easiest way to create a work flow or script to have a list searched before allowing a new entry to ensure a user doesn't create a duplicate record?

Example: Client list, one of the fields in the custom list is Full Name. How can I make the user search by Full Name to see if a record exists before allowing them to add a record to the list?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can use "Enforce Unique Values" in the field.

Go to the List -> List Settings -> click on the Field you want to change, and select Enforce Unique Values - Yes.